# Unable to resolve local network DNS Names from Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Unable to resolve Ubuntu DNS Name from Network

Tags: dns, netplan, lan, systemd-resolved

Not sure what happened today, but my Ubuntu server is no longer resolvable on the LAN, and nor can the Ubuntu server resolve any names on the LAN.  The Ubuntu Server can resolve external Domain Names successfully.

The Server is pingable via IP address, and it can successfully ping IP Addresses on the LAN.

For example I have a PC called "Office-PC" on the LAN, it has an IP Address of 192.168.2.4, if I try and ping the DNS name from the Ubuntu server I just get

```
ping office-pc
ping: office-pc: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I performed a trace on port 53 and I can see that there is a response from the DNS server with the correct address:

```
22:58:45.740134 IP 192.168.2.1.58302 > 192.168.2.101.53: 53394+ A? office-pc.home. (32)
22:58:45.740140 IP 192.168.2.1.58302 > 192.168.2.101.53: 26773+ AAAA? office-pc.home. (32)
22:58:45.741570 IP 192.168.2.101.53 > 192.168.2.1.58302: 20495- 1/0/0 A 192.168.2.4 (48)
```

my resolvectl output looks normal

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: uplink

Link 2 (enp65s0f0)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 192.168.2.101
    DNS Domain: home

Link 3 (enp65s0f1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

in my /etc/resolv.conf it shows correctly too:

```
nameserver 192.168.2.101
search home
```

my /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file looks normal too

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
        enp65s0f0:
            dhcp4: true
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.2.101]
                search: [home]
  version: 2
```

I am just lost now as to what could be causing this just for local LAN names, as you can see below, external addresses are resolvable

```
ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.187.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=9.03 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=8.85 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=8.56 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=9.54 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.557/8.994/9.540/0.357 ms
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `nslookup office-pc` and include the output?

Comment: @dennis this is what I get

`nslookup office-pc`
`;; Warning: ID mismatch: expected ID 44978, got 49165`
`;; communications error to 192.168.2.101#53: timed out`
`;; Warning: ID mismatch: expected ID 44978, got 11537`
`;; communications error to 192.168.2.101#53: timed out`
`;; Warning: ID mismatch: expected ID 44978, got 23823`
`;; communications error to 192.168.2.101#53: timed out`
`;; no servers could be reached`

Comment: Interesting - it looks like you're sending a lookup, server returns an incorrectly formatted response. The issue is likely your DNS server - what is running it?

Comment: Sky broadband router is the DNS/DHCP server

Comment: Okay, it's hard to do further diagnosis without knowing their exact setup. I'd try rebooting the router and if that doesn't work, call customer support (which may have mixed results)

Comment: Router has been rebooted a number of times already.  Upon further investigation, it would appear that there are at least two systems on the network that when I ping them from my office PC they return a <hostname>.local instead of <hostname>.home which is strange, I know .local should not be used due to mDNS, but not sure if that is causing the issue

Comment: **Interesting - it looks like you're sending a lookup, server returns an incorrectly formatted response.**

But nslookup works fine for external domain names....bizarre

Comment: In that case, it might be good to let dhcp configure dns, instead of manually setting home as the search domain in your netplan

Comment: After some more troubleshooting, I think the DNS server on the Router is banjaxed, if I reboot the router, for a first few seconds after it has rebooted I can successfully ping the Ubuntu server via domain name, a few seconds later it stops responding.